# How did digital camera take a partially black and white photo?

Tags: digital, kodak, selective-color

I took a photo of San Francisco Bay using a Kodak Easyshare digital camera in 2007.  The photo came out with the grass in the foreground being green and the entire remainder of the photo (the bay, Alcatraz prison and the sky) came out in black and white.  How can this happen when the camera was only capable of taking color photos?  I took the photo on an overcast day.  I took thousands of photos using that camera and that is the only photo that ever came out that way.

Comment: It would be good if you could upload that image to show the effect.

Answer (score 6):

At least the later Easyshare cameras had a feature called "spot color": it would allow you to select a color, and the rest of the picture is converted to black and white.

I was able to find this feature described for an [Easyshare camera introduced in 2011](http://www.kodak.com/ek/US/en/Kodak_Launches_EASYSHARE_TOUCH_M5370_Digital_Camera_to_Take_Pictures_Simply.htm) (it says: "[...] or add in effects like background blur and spot color easily from the touch screen."). Not sure if your camera had a touch screen, but you might have accidentally enabled the effect for the one specific picture, causing the effect you describe.

Comment: Thank you, Robert.  That seems to be the likely explanation.  I feel foolish saying that I had no idea my camera had such a setting but apparently it did and somehow it came into play temporarily for that one shot.  I've always had trouble "navigating" through digital gadgets and I always set my digital cameras to "AUTO" focus mode.  I usually get good photos (I think) in spite of my ignorance.  Still, your answer seems to be the explanation as to why that photo came out that way.  Thank you... you answered a question I've had for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

By *far* the most likely explanation here is that you put the camera into a "spot color" mode for that one photo. The cheap digital camera I had in 2007 was more than capable of taking spot color photos, so I don't see any reason your camera wouldn't have been able to.

Comment: "*the grass in the foreground being green* and the entire remainder of the photo... came out in black and white"

Comment: I did not know my camera could do that as I have never gone beyond the  "AUTO"  setting on any of the 3 digital cameras I've ever owned.  Still, some sort of glitch must have made that photo come out with that particular camera feature in play.  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  Thanks, Phillip.

Comment: @Max Errr... yep. Edited for "spot color" rather than "monochrome", but exactly the same point applies.

Comment: Well, I'm embarrassed...  but at least I know what happened.  I still don't know HOW it happened but it surely did and, as a result, I ended up with a very nice photo and a surprise as well.  Thanks again.